# How to access fields from another view in an UNION ALL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently I am using an `'UNION ALL'`, because their ID's are completely different from each other. This is because of the WHERE condition in each view. The first view (v1) calculates for all the 5 types, only the hours that are smaller than 1000. For the second view (v2) the same types, but only the hours that are greater than 1000.

**EDITED:**

This is my code:

```
 SELECT
         skill_type
        ,sched_hours AS sched_hours_online
        ,actual_hours AS actual_hours_online
        ,'' AS sched_hours_offline
        ,'' AS actual_hours_offline
    FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
           myID
          ,skill_type 
          ,sched_hours
          ,actual_hours
    FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT
              ex.myID AS myID
             ,ex2.skill_type AS skill_type
             ,SUM(ex2.sched_hr) OVER (PARTITION BY ex2.skill_type) AS sched_hours
             ,SUM(ex2.actual_hr) OVER (PARTITION BY ex2.skill_type) AS actual_hours
          FROM example ex
          --
          JOIN example_join ex1
            ON ex1.myID = ex.myID
          --
          JOIN example_join2 ex2
            ON ex2.myID = ex1.myID
          WHERE (ex1.total_hours < 1000)
    ) v1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT
           myID
          ,skill_type 
          ,sched_hours
          ,actual_hours
    FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT
              ex.myID AS myID
             ,ex2.skill_type AS skill_type
             ,SUM(ex2.sched_hr) OVER (PARTITION BY ex2.skill_type) AS sched_hours
             ,SUM(ex2.actual_hr) OVER (PARTITION BY ex2.skill_type) AS actual_hours
          FROM example ex
          --
          JOIN example_join ex1
            ON ex1.myID = ex.myID
          --  
          JOIN example_join2 ex2
            ON ex2.myID = ex1.myID
          WHERE (ex1.total_hours > 1000)
    ) v2
)
```

This is what I currently see in my output:

[image]

The `'UNION ALL'` works great as you can see in the image. But unfortunately it is not exactly what I want. The first record (357.17 and 296.79) should be in the right column under the second record of the same TYPE called `"SCHED_HOURS_OFFLINE"` and `"ACTUAL_HOURS_OFFLINE"`. But I don't know how to do that. I thought I could do something like this:

```
SELECT
         skill_type
        ,v1.total_sched_hours AS sched_hours_online
        ,v1.total_actual_hours AS actual_hours_online
        ,v2.total_sched_hours AS sched_hours_offline
        ,v2.total_actual_hours AS actual_hours_offline
    FROM (
```

But for some reason I don't have access to v1 and v2.

Comment: Are the skill types the same across the tables? Can you join on those instead?

Comment: It is not about the join itself. If I can access the fields like v1 and v2, it would be fine. But I can't. Probably I am doing something wrong. Or it is just not possible.

Comment: Please refer to @llythya's question again. You require output on the same line with the *SKILL_TYPE*, so how online/offline pairings be side by side to each other and not be related. What if v2 has more rows than v1?

Comment: I understand what @Ilythya mean, but it is a little bit more complicated than that. It doesn't matter if v2 has more rows than v1. The two views are not related to each other, because of different ID'S. The first view shows per type all the hours that are smaller than 1000 (online hours), and the second view shows per type all the hours that are greater than 1000 (offline hours). I edited my post. Hopefully I explained it better now.

Comment: Sure. But you said both views are showing hours *per type* - and if the type is the same, probably what you actually want is a full outer join between the two views on skill_type - NOT a union all.

Comment: what is the determining factor/column that makes it online or offline hours?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have empty columns in each of the selects which you want to combine by the union all.

```
SELECT
     skill_type
    ,sched_hours AS sched_hours_online
    ,actual_hours AS actual_hours_online
    ,'' AS sched_hours_offline
    ,'' AS actual_hours_offline
FROM (...

UNION ALL

SELECT
     skill_type
    ,'' AS sched_hours_online
    ,'' AS actual_hours_online**
    ,sched_hours  AS sched_hours_offline
    ,actual_hours AS actual_hours_offline
FROM (...
```